# Windows 7 system font for hangul

Tags: windows-7, korean

### tl;dr What font do I need for being able to read hangul on Windows 7 Professional?

Back in the good old days, I've removed everything Asian from my Windows 7 install using NTLite since it's good for nothing anyway (the stuff is huge, and I can't read it!) and it reduces the total install size by about 50%.

Now, 5 years later it turns out that this was a really, really ingenious idea because I'm planning to learn Korean and guess what... hangul characters show as "unknown character" boxes. That's immensely helpful, isn't it.

To clarify, I'm not interested in localizing the UI, I need no language bar, no keyboard / input methods, none of that. I just want to be able to read hangul characters in the web browser (or, in general).

So the reason this isn't working is, of course, a system font is missing. I could probably extract that one from the install image manually, or if nothing helps just copy it over from a pristine, non-stripped Windows install in a virtual machine. No problem there.

Only just... *which font*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some experimentation, it turns out that all that is missing to "work" (somehow) is `batang.ttc`, although Batang isn't very nice and readable at small sizes.

In order to get nice results with small text sizes as well, `gulim.ttc`as well as `malgun.ttf` are needed, too.

All of these can just be copied from and to the `Windows/Fonts` directory, done.